# Get image from external web service and pass it to another express js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, rest, express

I have a external web service, which returns image.

and I have node express route which call that external web service.

I am struggling to pass the returned object of external web service (which is image) as express route's  return object

here is this example, I am trying to get image from external URL and passing it as it is.. it doesn't work, can someone help me know to do so?

```
exports.getImage = function (req, res) {

    var http = require('http');


    var options = {
        host: 'http://www.gettyimages.co.uk',
        path: '/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "content-type": "image/jpeg"
        }
    };

    var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
        var imagedata = '';
        response.setEncoding('binary');

        response.on('data', function(chunk){
            imagedata += chunk
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            console.log('imagedata: ', imagedata);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' });
            res.send(imagedata);
        });
    }).on("error", function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message, e);
    });

    request.end();

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the existing code is that `res.send()` defaults to a non-binary encoding when you pass it a string, so your data will end up getting mangled because of that.

Secondly, you're better off just streaming the data instead, that way you aren't buffering the entire image in memory every time. Example:

```
var request = http.get(options, function(response) {
  res.writeHead(response.statusCode, {
    'Content-Type': response.headers['content-type']
  });
  response.pipe(res);
}).on("error", function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message, e);
});
```

Lastly, the `host` value is wrong, it should just be hostname only (no scheme): `www.gettyimages.co.uk`. Also, setting `"content-type": "image/jpeg"` in the request `headers` doesn't make sense (and can be removed) since you're not sending a jpeg image in your request.